# Root Polynom and eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be an $N \times N$ matrix. We know that $A^2 - 2A + I = 0$ so we need to prove that $A = I$ or give a counterexample.

We know that $(A-I)^2 = 0$ but I don't know how we can get from the equation ( 1 eigenvalue from Algebraic multiplicity = 2 ) ?

**Edit:** We know that $A$ is diagonalizable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is diagonalisable, so $A = S D S^{-1}$ where $D$ is diagonal, then $D^2 - 2 D + I = S^{-1} (A^2 - 2 A + I) S = 0$.  The diagonal elements of $D^2 - 2 D + I$ are $\lambda^2 - 2 \lambda + 1$ corresponding to the diagonal elements $lambda$ of $D$, so $\lambda = 1$ is the only possibility.  Thus $D = I$ and $A = S I S^{-1} = I$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

From $(A-I)^2 = 0$ it follows that $1$ is the only eigenvalue of $A$. Since $A$ is diagonalizable we get $A = I$.

Comment: Sorry forget to mention that A is diagonalisable :(

Comment: @RaphaelBellahsen Ok, have a look now.

Comment: How do you know its the only eigenvalue possible ?

Comment: @RaphaelBellahsen The polynomial $(x-1)^2$ annihilates $A$ so the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $(x-1)^2$. The eigenvalues of $A$ are precisely the zeroes of the minimal polynomial.

Comment: @RaphaelBellahsen Or simpler, if $Ax = \lambda x$ for $x \ne 0$, then $$0 = (A-I)^2x = (A^2-2A+I)x = (\lambda^2 - 2\lambda +1)x$$
so $\lambda^2 - 2\lambda + 1 = 0$, or $\lambda = 1$.

Comment: Is there any link to The Cayley-Hamilton Theorem ?

Comment: @RaphaelBellahsen Not really. If $p$ is a polynomial such that $p(A)= 0$, then all eigenvalues of $A$ are roots of $p$. Indeed, if $Ax = \lambda x$ for $x \ne 0$, we have $$p(\lambda)x = p(A)x = 0$$
so $p(\lambda) = 0$. Cayley-Hamilton tells us that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ annihilates $A$ so it follows that all eigenvalues of $A$ are zeroes of the characteristic polynomial, but we already knew that.